# how to route to a new page without the Cupertino bottom bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the Cupertino tab to display a bottom navigation bar and it working good. Now, I want to route to a new page from one of the tab pages (E.g login)and not have the bottom navigation. I tried the code below and  I still see the bottom navigation.

How can I route to a page and not show the bottom navigation

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
     title: "login",
     builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen(),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static methods on `Navigator`, like `Navigator.push` or `Navigator.of` use the nearest enclosing `Navigator` of the `context` argument. When using a `CupertinoTabScaffold`, every tab has a nested `Navigator` to provide in-tab navigation, as is the default iOS behavior. You can get the root `Navigator` using `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)` and push your route on that:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(route)
```

More info about navigators in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)